# What should be done with this very bad link?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

At [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467052/how-to-set-right-alignment-in-jtable-cell) is a link that at one time led me to a bogus blue screen phishing page and now just leads to a page warning of phishing, advising to report to Google, but it's not a secure page.

Name of link as written on page with caret (`^`) replacing dots and `http` and `://` omitted:

articles^techrepublic^com^com/5100-10878_11-5032692^html

Comment: Just flag for moderator attention.

Comment: And be very specific on what is wrong with it.  Point to this meta question if needed.

Comment: @ryanyuyu is correct. Elaboration is important for moderator flags. You're already requesting their time, don't waste it by giving them an unclear request.

Comment: A little tip: SO does not have "topics" or "threads". It's a Q&A, not a forum.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit--good point. I only sometimes call the items in ... question ...  `"Questions"`. They do seem like "topics" and feel like "threads", especially since most of the time the "Question" is a *statement* or hardly a sentence at all. But thanks.

Comment: Seems that since this question was asked the techrepublic website has been "fixed"?

Comment: @rogerdpack no, check the edit history.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Edit it to point to the real article: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3467117/revisions

[There are 400-some of these links laying around...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Atechrepublic.com.com)

**Update:** I replaced all of these links with links to archive.org. Also all links to blog.techrepublic.com.com. I did this on Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault. If I missed any such links anywhere else, please correct them manually.

And big thanks for bringing this up here!

Comment: Since @Shog9 has taken care of the problem I identified, is this the end? I mean, I shouldn't still flag for moderator attention, should I? Problem solved, right?

Comment: Flagging for mod attention in this case wouldn't accomplish much anyway; the site is down, replaced by something awful; mods can't fix that any more than you can. Best we can do is try to make the links work

Comment: Can we just globally prevent URLs containing `.com.com` in the hostname from being emitted as hyperlinks?

Comment: Not easily, @Ben - also, that would break all of those archive.org links I just created.

Comment: @Shog9: No, it wouldn't break archive.org links, since they have `.com.com` in the URL but not in the **hostname**.  The hostname on those is exactly `web.archive.org`, no `.com.com` to be seen.

Comment: My mistake; but yeah, there's no existing functionality for something like this. At minimum, it'd require re-rendering all matching posts with some sort of extra post-processor - and if we're gonna do that, might as well just point the links somewhere useful. @Ben

Comment: I mean for all future posts going forward.  `.com.com` is a cancer, it never will have value as a link, but a question could legitimately ask how to detect and block it.  There must be something that determines when text contains a URL, and just configure it to return not-a-URL when for `.com.com` hosts.

Comment: Oh. Yeah, could probably just outright *block* those from being posted. Though I'm not sure anyone is still using them, given they seem to redirect to horrible places and aren't showing up much in search results anymore.

Comment: There seem to be an additional 20-ish hits for `url:.com.com` which don't match your original search, but I can't manage to write a query to return the set difference (it should be `url:.com.com -url:techrepublic.com.com` but that isn't negating properly)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to do the discussion links (no articles. or blog. prefix) - done now. @Ben

Comment: @Shog9 What about dead links from long-accepted answers?

Comment: What about them, @OhBeWise? Fix 'em if you can.

Comment: @Shog9 I wish I could. Yesterday, I came across [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/766250/3773066) with a dead link, but I haven't a clue how to fix such a thing. Other comments made the link sound like the most promising part of the answer.

Comment: Dead links tend to properly show a 404, and that's going to be very hard to police.   Malicious links, even if they started benign, need moderation much more urgently

Comment: `COM.COM` used to be owned by CNET.

Comment: @tepples: [...but they sold it.](https://blog.whitehatsec.com/why-com-com-should-scare-you/)